# get number of transactions within a certain month and year

Tags: c#, linq

I know how to get the number of transactions but how do I get the count that occurred for a specific month?

If I want March 2013's transaction for instance?

Here is my current query:

```
  textBox_PaymentsCount.Text = 
       (from tot in _entities.Payments
        where tot.CorporationId == _currentcorp.CorporationId && 
         tot.Result != null
          select tot).Count().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I need to minimize my query down by the field `TransactionDateTime`.

I tried by specifying the first and last day, but the last day varies by month.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another condition into `where` clause and use `DateTime.Month` and `DateTime.Year` properties:

```
tot.DateProperty.Month == 3 && tot.DateProperty.Year == 2013
```

Whole query should look like that:

```
textBox_PaymentsCount.Text = 
    (from tot in _entities.Payments
     where tot.CorporationId == _currentcorp.CorporationId && 
     tot.Result != null &&
     tot.DateProperty.Month == 3 && tot.DateProperty.Year == 2013
     select tot).Count().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: nice! I didn't know this existed! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2):

> but the last day varies by month.

You can just use the first day of the current and next month, and use `<` the next month:

```
&& TransactionDateTime >= firstDayOfThisMonth 
&& TransactionDateTime < firstDayOfNextMonth
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
where tot.TransactionDateTime.Year == year && tot.TransactionDateTime.Month == month
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var from = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
var until = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1);

....
where tot.CorporationId == _currentcorp.CorporationId 
&& tot.Result != null
&& tot.TransactionDateTime > from && tot.TransactionDateTime < until
....
```

Answer (score 0):

first day i = 1
and last day = 30 or 31 or 28 / 29
create a structure linking the months to correspondind last dates 
and as per the month input 
it will take the corresponding the last day 
and then will calculate the no. of transactions for a given month

Answer (score 0):

Just get the month and year from you TrasanctionDateTime

tot.TransationDate.Year == year && tot.Transaction.Month == month